# Saving the plot points in android to use in different resolution devices

Tags: android

**What is happening:**

**Steps i am following:**
`create a button` -> `create a button` -> `save its coordinates` -> `send to server` -> `retrieve it on a tab` -> `display it`

---

On the smaller screen the button created and showing well
when i replot the coordinates taken from smaller phone on a larger phone there is lot of area on x and y axis that is unused. and the area where points are aggregated also very small

---

***How to resolve this !!***

### myXml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:id="@+id/rootId">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Word"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/txtWordId" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/grid">



            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/canvasLayoutId"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/txtId"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="150sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text=" تَشَاءُ"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>




        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomPannel"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="3.5">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Reset"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_empty"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:id="@+id/btnResetId"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Next"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_empty"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:id="@+id/btnActionId"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Submit"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_empty"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:id="@+id/btnSubmitId"/>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/stringInstruction"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtInstructionId" />



</LinearLayout>
```

---

### Method I am using to save create button on the screen inside relative layout

```
 private void createButton(float x, float y) {
        Button btn = new Button(ActDrawAreaTwo.this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(40, 40);
        bp.leftMargin = (int) x;
        bp.topMargin = (int) y;

        //Assign the Id to the button
        btn.setLayoutParams(bp);
        CommonFunctions.setBackgroundDrawable(btn, ActDrawAreaTwo.this, R.drawable.white_circle_dot);//Set Button Drawable

        //Update the new nearest x and y params
        String mStr = (int) x + "," + (int) y;
        btn.setTag(mStr);
        canvasLayoutId.addView(btn);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code to get Device's height and width and save them to variable, like this

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

After getting your X and Y use below mentioned function to get percentage

```
int percentageX= (int)((x*100)/width)
int percentageY= (int)((y*100)/height)
```

Save these as coordinates in server

Now before you reuse the plot points from server. Convert them back to Pixels using

```
int newX = (int)((x*width)/100)
int newy = (int)((y*height)/100)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, [+1] for precision !